# Getting release details during tests run

Tags: c#, azure-devops, mstest

I'm running automation tests using MsTest from Azure devops.
In the test TestCleanup I wish to know which release (Name+number) triggered the tests.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I doubt it. A build knows about test runs but tests do not know about builds. Can you not obtain what you need from dev ops build history?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch). Various values about a running build or release are set as environment variables, which you can retrieve during your tests. `Release.ReleaseName` contains the release name.